# how to include database login for connect to mysqli with file configuration .env?

Tags: php, mysqli

i try include config of login database with file .env but not work.

here my config file .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

here my code :

```
<?php

    include_once ".env";

    $host = "DB_HOST";
    $user = "DB_USERNAME";
    $pass = "DB_PASSWORD";
    $db = "DB_DATABASE";

    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

    if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
        {
            printf("<br><br><br>");
            printf("Error connect: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
            exit();
        }

    echo 'laravel';

?>
```

i try with my code but i get error : `Error connect: Unknown MySQL server host 'DB_HOST' (2)`

Comment: You are simply setting ```$host``` to the string value ```DB_HOST```. Look into the ```getenv``` function

Comment: Basically anything you include, HAS to be Valid PHP and yours is not

Comment: You can try [How to create environment variable like laravel](https://medium.com/@hfally/how-to-create-an-environment-variable-file-like-laravel-symphonys-env-37c20fc23e72)

Comment: can someone fix my code please?

Comment: Also please note you should not print out the error messages! Enable error reporting and forget about manual error checking. https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `include` only for PHP files. But to read such a file you will need another function called `parse_ini_file()`:

```
$dbconfig = parse_ini_file(".env");

$host = $dbconfig["DB_HOST"];
$user = ...
```

Or you can use a dedicated library such as [phpdotenv](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv)

Comment: but im still get this error : No database selected my query is correct

Answer (score -2):

I never really used Laravel, but maybe this would help?

```php
$a = fopen(".env", "r");
$settings = array();
if ($a) {
    while (($b = fgets($a)) !== false) {
        $setting = explode("=", $b);
        array_push($settings, array($setting[0]=>$setting[1]));
    }
    fclose($a);
} else {
    // Error for not being able to open file.
}
var_dump($settings);
```

It should now have all the settings in `$settings`.
Then use it like this?

```php
<?php
$a = fopen(".env", "r");
$settings = array();
if ($a) {
    while (($b = fgets($a)) !== false) {
        $setting = explode("=", $b);
        array_push($settings, array($setting[0]=>$setting[1]));
    }
    fclose($a);
} else {
    // Error for not being able to open file.
}

$mysqli = new mysqli($settings["DB_HOST"], $settings["DB_USERNAME"], $settings["DB_PASSWORD"], $settings["DB_DATABASE"]);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("<br><br><br>");
    printf("Error connect: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
echo 'laravel';
?>
```

Comment: but im still get this error :  `No database selected`
my query is correct